# 3Des decryption using different key (from encryption state), can decrypt successfully

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encryption-symmetric, 3des

I've tried TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider(). 
And I've change Encrypt/Decrypt key a bit, wonder why different key can decrypt encrypted text successfully.

(Also I've tried With or Without specified different IV, same result)

The difference in the keys is at `TestKey1(5) = 4, TestKey2(5) = 5`

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim tDESalg As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

        Dim Testkey1 As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Z4xC#49S3$3!A470&i0O51@5")

        ' Create a string to encrypt.
        Dim sData As String = "Here is some data to encrypt."

        ' Encrypt the string to an in-memory buffer.
        Dim Data As Byte() = TrippleDESCSPSample.EncryptTextToMemory(sData, Testkey1, tDESalg.IV)

        Dim Testkey2 As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Z4xC#59S3$3!A470&i0O51@5")
        Debug.Print(Testkey1.Equals(Testkey2))

        ' Decrypt the buffer back to a string.
        Dim Final As String = TrippleDESCSPSample.DecryptTextFromMemory(Data, Testkey2, tDESalg.IV)

        ' Display the decrypted string to the console.
        Response.Write(Final)
    End Sub



End Class


Class TrippleDESCSPSample


    Public Shared Function EncryptTextToMemory(Data As String, Key As Byte(), IV As Byte()) As Byte()
        Try
            ' Create a MemoryStream.
            Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()

            ' Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            ' and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            Dim cStream As New CryptoStream(mStream, New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            ' Convert the passed string to a byte array.
            Dim toEncrypt As Byte() = New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(Data)

            ' Write the byte array to the crypto stream and flush it.
            cStream.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length)
            cStream.FlushFinalBlock()

            ' Get an array of bytes from the 
            ' MemoryStream that holds the 
            ' encrypted data.
            Dim ret As Byte() = mStream.ToArray()

            ' Close the streams.
            cStream.Close()
            mStream.Close()

            ' Return the encrypted buffer.
            Return ret
        Catch e As CryptographicException
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Shared Function DecryptTextFromMemory(Data As Byte(), Key As Byte(), IV As Byte()) As String
        Try
            ' Create a new MemoryStream using the passed 
            ' array of encrypted data.
            Dim msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(Data)

            ' Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            ' and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            Dim csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)

            ' Create buffer to hold the decrypted data.
            Dim fromEncrypt As Byte() = New Byte(Data.Length - 1) {}

            ' Read the decrypted data out of the crypto stream
            ' and place it into the temporary buffer.
            csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length)

            'Convert the buffer into a string and return it.
            Return New ASCIIEncoding().GetString(fromEncrypt)
        Catch e As CryptographicException
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Interesting. Making other changes to the key causes it to fail, as far as I can see...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, wrong key may sometimes caused exception and sometimes ok no exception.

Comment: For Those who stumble upon this thread, the short answer to my question (by reading link provided above by @xanatos) is
1. Even 3DES's key size is 24bytes (=24 characters), but it only takes 7bit from each byte as a key, the left over bit (of each byte) is Parity bit which many 3DES library decided to omit them.
2. Therefore, changing fifth byte from "4" to "5" doesn't make any changes in those 7bits honour by .Net Library, so the both considered the same Key. 
3. Which in turn, make decryption legally possible.

Thanks @xanatos